# ISIS under NFC in features.xml Galaxy S4 -- Can I enable Google Wallet

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4, verizon, google-wallet

I rooted my phone again (I accidently downloaded the update that caused me to loose root). I was looking to add features to my TouchWiz like infinite loop for the home-screen and that information is stored in features.xml.

I found the NFC location and ISIS was under one of the tags. Is it possible to make Google Wallet work by changing some of these values?

Here's a screen shot:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to *prepare* (see below) your phone for Google Wallet by modifying the following parts in feature.xml:

Replace

```
<CscFeature_NFC_SetSecureEventType>ISIS</CscFeature_NFC_SetSecureEventType>
<CscFeature_SmartcardSvc_SetAccessControlType>GPAC, MODE1</CscFeature_SmartcardSvc_SetAccessControlType>
```

with

```
<CscFeature_NFC_SetSecureEventType>GOOGLE</CscFeature_NFC_SetSecureEventType>
<CscFeature_SmartcardSvc_SetAccessControlType>GAC</CscFeature_SmartcardSvc_SetAccessControlType>
```

Remove

```
<CscFeature_SmartcardSvc_HideTerminalCapability>eSE</CscFeature_SmartcardSvc_HideTerminalCapability>
```

Add

```
<CscFeature_NFC_DefaultCardModeConfig>eSE</CscFeature_NFC_DefaultCardModeConfig>
<CscFeature_NFC_CardModeRoutingTypeForEse>ROUTE_ON_WHEN_SCREEN_ON</CscFeature_NFC_CardModeRoutingTypeForEse>
```

Note, however, that this will only prepare the NFC service of your device to be able to interact with Google Wallet. There are still some more problems:

1. Google Wallet will still try to detect your mobile network operator and will typically refuse to work if you use a Verizon SIM card. (Possibly even your phone's Verizon-specific model number might be enough for GW to refuse to work.)
2. Same applies for getting GW through Play Store.
3. I'm not sure that Google has the keys for access to the embedded secure element on any of the ISIS branded versions of the S4. If Google doesn't have them, it is **impossible** for Google Wallet to install any of the on-card components of Google Wallet into the secure element. Thus, a secure element based Google Wallet would not work.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home. Thanks for the answer. It's worth a shot. My phone is rooted, obviously, but I don't want to install a custom recovery right now. I'm happy with Touchwiz. It's way better than Sense.

Comment: I did the mod for my phone and this was partly involved.